# Can .param change based on time?

Tags: ltspice

I am looking for an option to change the .param value dynamically during transient analysis. Is it possible ?
For example,
.param delvto = 300m from 1ns to 10ns
.param delvto = 120m from 10.1ns to 15ns

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: In what software?

Comment: I assume LTSpice, but how is anyone supposed to reasonably know what software you are using if you don't say it? Please think about how people who are going to read your question will interpret it. They aren't mind readers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. Param statements are evaluated during netlisting and will not re-evaluate as a function of time during a transient simulation.

If you explain your goal, however, we might be able to offer other solutions!

Comment: my goal is to change the offset applied in a sram bitcell, based on the operation cycle... for eg: during read cycle I want to apply 30mv offset the bitcell and during write cycle i may want to apply 20mv on the same device...

Comment: @praveenkumar You could use 20mV fixed, and 10mV added based on a conditional, or, if you can afford it in your circuit, an A-device (which avoids discontinuities).

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but how do we do this.. could you provide an example for syntax....